# Heat map of features and weights

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I have run a machine learning algorithm. Now I have a series whose index=features of the resulting model and column is the correponding weights.

I want to show the features and their weights as a heat map where I want to show features with high weights darker than the features with lighter weights. Is it also possible to kind of show positive weights in different color than negative weights?. Like all features with positive weights like green and within positive weights can have dark, light based on value of weight, while all negative weights features as red , and with negative weights again intensity of the color changes with respective to absolute value.

Here is how a typical feature weight matrix looks like. Its a series with index as features.

```
adm_hr_ls_7                                            [-0.0151751599842]
admittype_elective                                     [-0.0767214648205]
admission_age_inyears                                    [0.629567909855]
patient_race_caucasian                                    [-0.0543069188]
gender_female                                          [-0.0831126807492]
marital_status_married                                 [-0.0219135568879]
religion_none                                          [-0.0629291312093]
employmentstatus_retired                                [0.0620868529898]
employmentstatus_not_employed                           [0.0195733078954]
```

Edit:

Your code gave me something like this

[image]

I am looking for a grid where all top positive feature are shown with intensity of color guided by the abs value of the weights. All positive weights would have one color with varying intensity. Similar all top negative weights (again top in abs terms) would have one color with varying intensity corresponding to abs weight size . Your code is first not able to get the labels properly aligned. Secondly it is giving lot of colors.

Lets say this is the data.

```
admission_age_inyears                                           [3.86703690989]
emergencydepartmentlengthofstayminutes                          [3.84708584711]
current_los_from_admissions                                     [3.83956976064]
total_time_in_progressive_inpatient                             [3.63955027973]
total_time_spent_inpatient                                      [2.59339330312]
nbr_of_hosp_last_90_days                                        [2.44570139977]
total_time_spent_in_er                                          [2.37914969651]
prior_admittype_emergency                                       [2.18467109815]
nbr_inpatient_visits                                            [2.09615621507]
curr_rx_gen_atorvastatin_calcium                                [2.08752966479]
substanceusehistory                                             [1.91340885366]
timetofirstnurseminutes  
to_be_discharged_to_hospice                                   [-0.323042070071]
tot_est_median_age_years                                       [-0.33548236033]
total_current_pharma_laxatives                                [-0.348768315972]
curr_rx_gen_rivaroxaban                                       [-0.359848868739]
dis_notes_contact_info                                        [-0.360264143656]
total_speak_indo_european                                     [-0.373310297224]
patient_race_african_american                                 [-0.391335453176]
financialclass_commercial                                     [-0.427463083689]
curr_rx_gen_epinephrine_hcl                                    [-0.44205667523]
tot_est_age_55_to_64_years                                    [-0.451699358283]
percent_high_school_grad_or_higher                            [-0.461380248502]
tot_est_age_65_to_74_years
```

All I want is that top ten-15 positive weights should be represented by one common color (lets say green) such that the intensity of the color for each feature is defined by the abs value of the corresponding feature weight. Similar all negative weights feature (top 10-15) should be represented by one common color like red and the intensity of the color is defined by the abs value of the corresponding feature weights

EditII
[image]

Edit3:

I ran this code. Gave an error

```
n_features = 50

feature_names = ["feature_"+str(i) for i in range(n_features)]
weights = coef_lren.values

# select top 15 high and low features
indices = np.argsort(np.abs(weights))
n_top = 15
top = np.hstack((indices[:n_top], indices[-n_top:]))[::-1]

vmax = np.abs(weights).max()

plt.clf()
plt.imshow(weights[top].reshape((-1,1)),interpolation='nearest', cmap="seismic", vmin=-vmax, vmax=vmax)
plt.axes().xaxis.set_visible(False)
plt.colorbar()

tick_marks = np.arange(2 * n_top)
plt.yticks(tick_marks, [feature_names[i] for i in top])

   433             not np.can_cast(self._A.dtype, np.float)):
--> 434             raise TypeError("Image data can not convert to float")


TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. People typically use the "seismic" colormap. http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

Comment: can u provide an example?

Comment: Online documentation already as a lot of examples... just add the kw `cmap="seismic"` in `imshow` or which ever plotting function you fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there's a tiny bit more work to do, this should give you good results:

```
# define the range for the color mapping
# make sure the color map is centered on 0
# >> use maximum absolute value and not the real min and max (default behaviou)
vmax = np.abs(my_weights).max()

plt.imshow(my_weights.reshape((-1,1)), cmap="seismic", vmin=-vmax, vmax=vmax)

# add feature names
feature_names = ['foo', 'bar', ...]
tick_marks = np.arange(len(feature_names))
plt.yticks(tick_marks, feature_names)
```

EDIT:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

n_features = 50

feature_names = ["feature_"+str(i) for i in range(n_features)]
weights = np.random.randn(n_features)

# select top 15 high and low features
indeces = np.argsort(weights)
n_top = 15
top = np.hstack((indeces[:n_top], indeces[-n_top:]))[::-1]

vmax = np.abs(weights).max()

plt.clf()
plt.imshow(weights[top].reshape((-1,1)),interpolation='nearest', cmap="seismic", vmin=-vmax, vmax=vmax)
plt.axes().xaxis.set_visible(False)
plt.colorbar()

tick_marks = np.arange(2 * n_top)
plt.yticks(tick_marks, [feature_names[i] for i in top])
```

[image: result]

Comment: Here your my_features is the series I mentioned above? Also is it possible if on X-axis I can have top ten features and on Y -axis the corresponding effect for target variable value (1 or 0)?. And same concept again

Comment: Yes `my_features` would be the numeric values you want to display, call it weights if you like. For your other question I don't understand what you want...

Comment: Ok so how do I see the name of the features?. The weights would be the color intensity but I also want to see the weights of the features. 

Basically there are two things. First is is it possible to get a heat map of all the features and their corresponding weights(as color) in a grid format such that positive weights are represented by one color and negative weights by other color and size of weights is defined by the color intensity. 

If first can be done , then I can think of second where it would be a grid of target variable (1 or 0) - y axis with features weights (x axis). Focus on 1st

Comment: First is already solved (or you have to explain exactly what is wrong with my answer), if the only problem is the missing feature names, you can add then to your figure with `plt.yticks`, see edit. Second is not any clearer.

Comment: New edit gives exactly what you want. Only modifications are: turning of the color interpolation, and selecting the most extreme features as requested.

Comment: Ok this is cool. Just a question. Is it possible to kind of get a heat map as a square or rectangular grid? I am not sure what we can put on the y axis but something like the one I attached in the edit. Pls check

Comment: Of course you can, just pass a 2D matrix to `imshow` instead of 1D vector. But as you said, the axes should probably correspond to something real like in your example for the plot to make any sense.

Comment: That's your job to track down your bug in your program. I don't know what you do and where the error is thrown! Are you sure `coef_lren.values` is a valid array?

Comment: It is. Its a series and when you do .values it gives the values of the series column

Comment: well my code works well with no modification correct? if so please accept the answer and try to debug your modifications alone or make a new post about it...

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works. Just a quick followup. Is it possible to broaden this graph. Like make the bars thick and spread the graph horizontally? I tried doing fig size. But it lengths and increasing the bar thickness and widening the plot

Comment: Also your first graph is also nice. The one you posted above Its pretty wide too Just that the feature names are all cluttered tougher and not spread. If you think that is possible so that is also nice

Comment: In general everything is possible, but you need to read the documentation a bit! To change the figure size, look for `plt.axes().set_aspect(...)`